# PIT mutation testing and Play framework (java)

Tags: java, playframework, pitest

Any idea on how we can use PIT mutation testing with a JAVA Play project ?

PIT provides integration with Maven, Ant and CLI , but I don't find any way to use it on a Play application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is an sbt plugin for pitest

https://github.com/hcoles/sbt-pit

But it hasn't been updated for a while.

If you setup the classpath and other parameters correctly there's no reason you can't use the cli tool on a play project, but this is fairly error prone.

Comment: thanks.  any advice on how to define the classpath properly for PIT with a play framework app?